# Add item to cart automatically when another product is present in magento cart

Tags: php, magento

I want to add item(one fix) to cart automatically when another product is present but quantity changes when main product quantity changed. Ex. if I add Product A with qty 1 in cart then product B with qty 1 will be add to cart same if I add Product A with qty 2 in cart then product B with qty 2. Please don't recommend any extension. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override cart controller. Register your module, then in your modules config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
   <modules>
     <Kreativ_Buynow>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
     </Kreativ_Buynow>
   </modules>
   <frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Kreativ_Buynow before="Mage_Checkout">Kreativ_Buynow</Kreativ_Buynow>
                </modules>
             </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
   </frontend>
 </config>
```

Then create CartController.php in controllers folder

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Kreativ_Buynow_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController{
 public function addAction(){ 

     foreach ($this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $items) {
        if($items->getProductId() == 933){
            $value = $items->getQty();
            $prd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(943);
            $this->_getCart()->addProduct($prd,$value)->save();
            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        }
     }
     return parent::addAction();
 }
```

Where I assumed if product with id 933 is present, then you are going to add product with id 943 in the cart.

Comment: you can even use a observer for event checkout_cart_product_add_after  to get above done. In that case you will not need to extend controller and change existing default magento functionality.

Comment: yes, that will be better, events are less likely to break after upgrade

Comment: Thanks Both of you. It's Work