# Magento - Removing then adding a product in controller gives price null

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm running magento CE 1.9, and facing a problem : when, in a checkout controller, I remove a product (any) and then I add another one, the price of this products becomes TEMPORARILY = 0.
I say temporarily because in the next step of the checkout the price is restored (or if I go back to cart).

Here is my snippet :

```
// Remove
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
  $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $product_id_01) {
      $itemId = $item->getItemId();
      $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
      break;
    }
  }

// Add
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id_02);
  $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
  $cart->init();
  $cart->addProduct($product, 1);
  $cart->save();
```

It's the same if I add the product using the quote.
Does anyone has an idea to solve this issue ?

**UPDATE**

It seems it is the

> $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();

that is in cause. Actually, if I remove the ->save() it works fine.
No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try this code

```
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(id);
        $this->_getCart()->addProduct($product,1)->save();
        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763228/add-item-to-cart-automatically-when-another-product-is-present-in-magento-cart/39765456#39765456).

Comment: Nope, the problem stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you to try the following code:

```
    $productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(id);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($productInstance, 1);
    $cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Let us know if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but it does not work. By the way setCartWasUpdated() is not wanted because it redirects to the cart instead of continuing using ajax of onepage checkout.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is the

> $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();

that is in cause. Actually, if I remove the ->save() it works fine.
No idea why.